# Communicate between Raspberry Pi and Arduino using Serial Pins? (C++, RP 4, Teensy 4.0)

Tags: c++, arduino, raspberry-pi, serial-port

I'm attempting to send a message over a serial connection from a Raspberry Pi 4 to a Teensy 4.0 (an Arduino-based microcontroller), from the TX-RX pins on the RP to the TX-RX pins on the Teensy.

I'm using C++ and the `wiringPi` library on the RP, with it's default Raspberry Pi OS.

I made a minimal setup, and simply tried sending a message from the RP to the Teensy.
However, it appears to not be working. While there are no displayed errors on the RP side, there is no message recieved on the Teensy side. I tried using both the `serialPuts` and `serialPrintf` commands on the RP side, but to no avail.

RP code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <cstdlib>

#include <wiringPi.h>
#include <wiringSerial.h>

int main()
{
    int port;

    if ((port = serialOpen("/dev/ttyAMA0", 9600)) < 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Unable to open serial device: %s\n", strerror(errno));

        return 1;
    }

    if (wiringPiSetup() == -1)
    {
        fprintf(stdout, "Unable to start wiringPi: %s\n", strerror(errno));
        
        return 1;
    }

    //serialPrintf(port, "test\n");
    serialPuts(port, "test");

    serialClose(port);

    return 0;
}
```

Teensy code:

```
#include "Arduino.h"

void setup() {
  Serial1.begin(9600);

  Serial.println("Listening...");
}

void loop() {
  if (Serial1.available() > 0) 
  {
    String incoming = Serial1.read();

    Serial.print("Recieved: ");
    Serial.println(incoming);
  }
}
```

Since I never attempted to connect via a serial port on a Linux before, I needed to find out what the `"/dev/ttyAMA0"` string meant. After doing some research, as far as I understand, that string represents a serial port that can be opened to communicate with another device and the RP.

I also tried running the `ls -l /dev/tty*` command on my RP in order to list all the supposed serial ports, however it prompted me with over 60 different `tty` ports... I'm not quite sure what to look for, or what port name to pick here. I also tried running the command with my Teensy disconnected, to try and see whether I can identify the port that's connected to the Teensy, however there wasn't a port that disappeared when I disconnected the Teensy...

I know for a fact that the Teensy is working, as I can access it from my Arduino IDE, and I verified that the TX-RX are cross-connected (RX->TX & TX->RX). I connected RP pin `GPIO 14` to Teensy pin `0`, and the RP pin `GPIO 15` to Teensy pin `1`.

I'm also powering the Teensy via the 5V and GND pins on the RP, not that it should matter for the serial communication.

Here's a diagram and an image of my setup:

[image]
[image]

Is there something I'm missing here? Should I be using another `tty` file in order to connect properly here? How do I decide which `tty` file to pick? Am I supposed to do some sort of pre-setup on the RP in order to use the serial pins?

Thanks for reading my post, any guidance is appreciated.

Comment: The code looks okay. By default Linux will grab the serial port and use it as a terminal. If you want to use it for other purposes you must prevent this. Run `sudo raspi-config` and check if it has the option `advanced options -> serial`. If it has, set it to disabled.

Comment: My RP does not have that option under the `advanced options` section of that config. Is that a bad sign? Should I have installed something prior to attempting to use the serial pins?

Comment: There are alternative method to disable it, see https://www.abelectronics.co.uk/kb/article/1035/serial-port-setup-in-raspberry-pi-os. Please noted that this is for Raspbian/Debian distribution, if you are a different Linux distribution, it might be different and I have no experience on those Linux distributions.

Comment: Actually it did have it, it was under `interface options` instead of `advanced options`. It asks me for 2 things; whether I would like for the login shell to be accessible over serial, and whether I would like the serial port hardware to be enabled. What should I pick for each one? They don't specify it for both in the guide you sent, only for the first prompt.

Comment: Enable Serial, disable login shell to be accessible over serial (this is the one that cause the interface to your Serial communication).

Comment: Just tried that, and I still recieve no response on the Teensy. Any other ideas? There may be some things in my code that are wrong...

Comment: 1) Did you reboot your RPI? 2) your python only send once, and require your Arduino to run first, otherwise it will miss the data.

Comment: 1) I did reboot my RP, 2) I am not using Python on my RP, I'm using C++ with the `wiringPi` library. And I am running the Arduino first, and then running the code on my RP.

Comment: You're trying to test with too many unknowns at once. You don't know if you have proper HW connections, and you have untested code on both ends of the serial link! All three could be a problem, so how would you know when you might have "fixed" something? Your RPi has a full-featured OS, so remove your untested code from the situation for now, and replace it with tested code, such as terminal emulation program, e.g. `minicom` or `picocom`.  Use an oscilloscope to check for UART signals.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out:

I was supposed to use the `/dev/ttyS0` serial port file when initializing my serial connection, instead of the `/dev/ttyAMA0` I was attempting to use previously.

It only appeared in the `ls -l /dev/tty*` list once I followed hcheung's suggestion of [disabling the login shell's accessibility over the serial port](https://www.abelectronics.co.uk/kb/article/1035/serial-port-setup-in-raspberry-pi-os), and re-running the command.